# A method that makes objects of another class

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

I need a method that returns a new object of a class. That method is in another class (I use java).

For example:

```
public Sale newSale(){
   Sale sale1 = new Sale();
}
```

I am afraid that when I use this method two times, I will only have 1 object because it has the same name (`sale1`).

Is there an alternative or is it not possible to do this?

Comment: public Sale newSale() { return new Sale(); } to be exact.

Comment: Don't be afraid , Open some basic Java tutorial that might help you from this nightmare !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call the method, this line will execute:

```
Sale sale1 = new Sale();
```

... And a brand-new object will be created, it doesn't matter *at all* that the same variable name is used - a new object will be allocated, the fact that the same name is reused is irrelevant; an object is not defined by its name. Now you only have to return it at the end:

```
return sale1;
```

Answer (score 2):

A new `Sale` object is created every time `new Sale()` is called.

```
public Sale newSale(){
   Sale sale1 = new Sale();
   return sale1;
}
```

You can test it with:

```
if(newSale() == newSale()){
  System.out.println("It's the same object!");

} else {
  System.out.println("They are distinct objects");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid, the name `sale1` is only used locally once per execution of your method, and you'll always get a new Object. Whoever calls `newSale` will always have a new `Sale` instance on every call.

Now, this is really basic Java, and you should definitely get to grips with Java a little more before asking the world ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Sale newSale(){
     return new Sale();
}
```

Every time you make a `new()` you are creating a new object, don't get confused with references.

And read a tutorial.

(recommended http://www.java-made-easy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You never actually return sale1 but if you did they'd be different objects. The name of the variable that is **temporarily holding an object** (technically a reference to an object) doesn't affect what that object actually is.

Remember the name of a variable is not the same as the name of an object. For example consider the following code:

```
Sale sale1=new Sale();
Sale sale2=sale1;
```

There you truely do have 1 object referenced by 2 variables. The object is not either Sale1 or Sale2 it is its own entity referenced by both.

Whenever you see the `new` keyword a new object has been created (whenever that line of code runs)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it works, but you have to return your newly created object.

But I think you don't really understand how OOP works.

```
public class Person {

    private String personName;

    //Cobstructor
    public Person(String name) {
        this.personName = name;
    }

    //Access name of person
    public String getName() {
        return this.personName;
    }

}
```

This is just a basic person class with a simple constructor and a private variable we can access through "getName()".

```
public class PersonCreator {

    //Constructor
    public PersonCreator() {
        //Empty constructor
    }

    //Create a new person
    public Person createPerson(String name) {
        //Create new instance of class " Person"
        Person aNewPerson = new Person(name);

        //Return the new instance which has been created by the Java VM and is more or less indepent of the identifier
        return aNewPerson;
    }

}
```

So if you create an instance of the class PersonCreator and use its method "createPerson(String name)" it returns everytime a complete new object with different variable values etc. Just an example:

```
//Create instance of PersonCreator
PersonCreator pc = new PersonCreator();

//Create two independent, different persons
Person p1 = pc.createPerson("Jeff");
Person p2 = pc.createPerson("Paul");

//Print names of persons
System.out.println(p1.getName());
System.out.println(p2.getName());
```

The output will be:

```
Jeff
Paul
```

As you can see you create with this piece of code, similar to your one, different, independent instances.

You can even check the address of those two instances/objects:

```
//Print addresses
System.out.println(p1);
System.out.println(p2);
```

The output will be some different memoty addresses. This proves that you create two non identical objects.

Furthermore you have to mention that your identifier "sale1" only identifies an object within your method. It's like babies beeing born in a hospital, here the hospital is your method. They leave the hospital, that's your return. But they can both have the same name, for example Edward, in the hospital. They are different because they have different parents, dates of birth etc. This is "handled" by the Java VM and the memory addresses.

I suggest you to read some basic articles about OOP to understand how it works properly. You can even just experiment with some simple code, like I did it for you theoretically in this answer.